# Android FireStore RecyclerView onSwiped method not updating RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a RecyclerView and have implemented a swipe-to-delete feature for it. However, I can't get it to work properly. I've tried many things, and they all change the behavior, but never make it work properly.

What I want to happen is:

1. I have 3 items in the view.
2. I swipe to delete item
3. Item 3 moves up to fill the space left by item 2's removal.

I've tried:

1. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
2. adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
3. adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, adapter.getItemCount())
4. combinations of the above
5. none of the above

Here is the relevant section of the code, and I'll be closely monitoring this thread so I can provide more code if deemed necessary.

This code is called in onCreate():

```
    adapter = new ClientAdapter(options);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    /*
     * This section handles what happens when you swipe an item in the recyclerView list
     */
    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            adapter.deleteClient(position);

            // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            // adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            // adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, adapter.getItemCount() - position);
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Again, I'll be monitoring so that I can provide more code if requested.

**Edit: Adding the code that deletes the item, which happens during the call above to**

```
adapter.deleteClient(position);
```

This code is in the Adapter class, ClientAdapter (which you can see invoked at the top of the previous code segment).

```
public void deleteClient(int position) {
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    //Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
                }
            });
}
```

And here is the ENTIRE adapter class:

```
public class ClientAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Client, ClientAdapter.ClientHolder> {

private OnItemClickListener listener;

/**
 * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.
 */
public ClientAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Client> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ClientHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Client model) {
    String lastNameWithComma = model.getLastName() + ", ";
    holder.textViewLastName.setText(lastNameWithComma);
    holder.textViewFirstName.setText(model.getFirstName());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ClientHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.client_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ClientHolder(v);
}

public void deleteClient(int position) {
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    //Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
                }
            });
}

class ClientHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewLastName;
    TextView textViewFirstName;

    public ClientHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewLastName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_tv_last_name);
        textViewFirstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_tv_first_name);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                    listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
}
```

Comment: You want to remove the item only from the adapter or also from the database?

Comment: @AlexMamo Both. I want it to be deleted from Firestore, I want it to disappear from the RecyclerView, and I want the RecyclerView to animate and update the list in realtime. And it seems like I've only been able to figure out how to do some of those, but not all of them at the same time!

Comment: Please add the code that removes the item from the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo Added! Please see above.